# Cannot use palette colors from MUI theme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use the default Material UI theme colors in a custom form element:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled } from '@mui/system';

const MyComponent = styled('div')(({theme}) => ({
  color: 'darkslategray',
  padding: theme.spacing(8),
  borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main,
}));

export default function BasicUsage() {
  return <MyComponent>Styled div</MyComponent>;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/hwpzf?file=/demo.tsx

Returns error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'main')

I can use the default spacing values or `borderRadius` provided by theme, but not the palette.

Comment: You should be importing `styled` from `@mui/material/styles` instead of `@mui/system` in order to have access to the default theme. See:https://mui.com/system/styled/#import-path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you [import](https://mui.com/system/styled/#import-path) the `styled` function from `@mui/system`:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/system';
```

The styling API from [`'@mui/system'`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/3e679ac9e368aeb170d564d206d59913ceca7062/packages/mui-system/src/styled.js) doesn't have a default theme, so you need to create a theme yourself and register in [`ThemeProvider`](https://mui.com/customization/theming/#theme-provider). If you wish to use the material default theme without writing extra code, use [`'@mui/material/styles'`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/3e679ac9e368aeb170d564d206d59913ceca7062/packages/mui-material/src/styles/styled.js):

```
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
```