# MUI error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'drawer')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using on project MUI v5.0.2. One week ago my project worked correctly (there were no errors), but today an error appeared out of nowhere (there were no changes in the code)

Error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'drawer')`

The code:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  ...
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1, //this line showed at error message
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
      easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
      duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
  },
  ...
}));
```

Also Visual Studio Code says:
`Property 'zIndex' does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme'`

I tried [this solution](https://mui.com/guides/migration-v4/#:%7E:text=issue%20on%20GitHub.-,%5BTypes%5D%20Property%20%22palette%22%2C%20%22spacing%22%20does%20not%20exist%20on%20type%20%27DefaultTheme%27,-Since) but it didn't help

Maybe someone knows how to solve it?

UPD: I tried to roll back to previous commits, but the same error occurs there, although this has not happened before

theme object:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      light: '#757ce8',
      main: '#3f50b5',
      dark: '#002884',
      contrastText: '#fff',
    },
    secondary: {
      light: '#ff7961',
      main: '#f44336',
      dark: '#ba000d',
      contrastText: '#000',
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: can you please share the value of `theme` object

Comment: @ziishaned added to the post

Comment: @cenak can you put your code on Codesandbox?

Comment: @NearHuscarl [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-blackwell-7r2iu?file=/src/components/Dashboard/Dashboard.js) it's very strange, but at sandbox it's working...

Comment: @cenak maybe check your [import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69400708/9449426) code

Comment: @NearHuscarl checked, but import code is ok. I copied code to sandbox without changing, only with deleting some sensitive parts and it's works on sandbox. I am checking this parts now, maybe them has bug, but its strange that week ago this code worked

Comment: Also, the sensitive parts does not interact in any way with the object indicated by the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's strange but solution is reinstalling all MUI packages

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar error with `undefined (reading 'contrastText')`
Took me a while to figure it out but this one came from a Chip comopnent that i used and the issue was that i used `danger` instead of `error` in one of the `<Chip />` components and that messed up the whole site.

Worse thing is that it doesn't tell me where this error is coming from

Comment: Thanks for sharing! That helped me narrow down my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you import it from the right packages. I did this mistake multiple times.

```
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles"
```

Also, make sure your **`useStlyes`** is wrapped by **`ThemeProvider`**.
Those also need to be imported from the right packages.

```
import { createTheme, Theme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles"
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error at `<Chip />` component with a custom color - `color="appGreen"`.

All i have to do is to add a `contrastText` prop to the color definition, like so:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    appGreen: {
      main: "#84F5BF",
      contrastText: "#303D45" // <--- HERE
    },
  },
```

Comment: This was precisely my issue, thank you! I hope MUI can throw more specific errors in this case going forward.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the root cause is but this hack worked for me:

```
import makeStyles from '@mui/styles/makeStyles'
import {useTheme} from '@mui/material/styles'

const useStyles = () => {
  const theme = useTheme()
  const useStylesInner = makeStyles(() => ({
    appBar: {
      zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    },
  }))
  return useStylesInner()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case i removed the color prop and replaced it with
sx={{bgcolor:'#000',color:'#fff'}} and it was fixed

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error where my deployed code started failing, but after reading answers from here, I figured it out that it was caused by a `chip`component which I introduced in last commit and all other error message was not so informative. I would like to thank you guys for putting your valuable info here:
I error which I was getting is :
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contrastText')`