# error - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'drawer')

Tags: javascript, material-ui, next.js, navigation-drawer, material-icons

I am trying to copy the exact code from Material UI Drawer to add on my own website. The link is https://mui.com/components/drawers/

```
  import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Drawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import ListItem from '@mui/material/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@mui/material/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@mui/material/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Mail';

export default function TemporaryDrawer() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    top: false,
    left: false,
    bottom: false,
    right: false,
  });

  const toggleDrawer = (anchor, open) => (event) => {
    if (event.type === 'keydown' && (event.key === 'Tab' || event.key === 'Shift')) {
      return;
    }

    setState({ ...state, [anchor]: open });
  };

  const list = (anchor) => (
    <Box
      sx={{ width: anchor === 'top' || anchor === 'bottom' ? 'auto' : 250 }}
      role="presentation"
      onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
      onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
    >
      <List>
        {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem button key={text}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem button key={text}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </Box>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {['left', 'right', 'top', 'bottom'].map((anchor) => (
        <React.Fragment key={anchor}>
          <Button onClick={toggleDrawer(anchor, true)}>{anchor}</Button>
          <Drawer
            anchor={anchor}
            open={state[anchor]}
            onClose={toggleDrawer(anchor, false)}
          >
            {list(anchor)}
          </Drawer>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I install both @mui/material and @mui/icons-material but it still shows this error.

Error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'drawer')

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: check your package json to see if if you have installed @emotion/react @emotion/styled
packages or not because according to documentation it is required ?

Comment: @ParthPatel yes, i have installed all the packages including "@emotion/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.5.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.5",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.5",

Comment: have you setup the react with typescript ?

Comment: because for react with typescript and without typescript there is a different syntax is there.

Comment: @ParthPatel No, I have not setup TypeScript but I am using Next.js framework.

Comment: You have to use the ts version of the code because next js is built with the typescript under the hood. https://mui.com/components/drawers/ has provided both the js and ts version.

Comment: @ParthPatel Now I have included the ts version of the code, but I cannot export the file now and it doesn't detect that it is a ts file.

Comment: you have to store the file with .ts extension

Comment: I have tried that too. But nothing works. At the end, it shows the same error.

Comment: Can you share the stack trace from the error you see? Also check [this SO question for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69481467/mui-error-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-drawer?rq=1)